# JSON.net TypeNameHandling : customize Auto

Tags: c#, json.net

I am serializing classes using JSON.net and using TypeNameHandling=Auto to insert the "$type" annotation. For the sake of the example, let's say this is my class:

```
[JsonObject]
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public ISomeInterfaceA MyA { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public ISomeInterfaceB MyB { get; set; }
}
```

With this, both "MyA" and "MyB" receive the "$type" attribute. Unfortunately, I am in a weird situation where I need "MyA" to have "$type" but "MyB" should **not** have "$type". Does json.net have anything that would allow me to customize the behaviour of TypeNameHandling.Auto so that I can manually choose where I want it or not?

As for why I would want to do such a thing, the complicated reason is that I am migrating to JSON.net from another legacy serializer, and I am attempting to minimize the differences between the old and the new serializer to avoid having to rewrite large amounts of javascript code consuming the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using a custom converter.

Say this is your class:

```
[JsonObject]
public class MyClass {
    [JsonProperty]
    public ISomeInterfaceA MyA { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(NoTypeConverter))]
    public ISomeInterfaceA MyB { get; set; }
}
```

We need a custom converter:

```
public class NoTypeConverter: JsonConverter<ISomeInterfaceA> {
    public override ISomeInterfaceA ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, ISomeInterfaceA existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, ISomeInterfaceA value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
       // Note: this is not the most efficient way to do this, but you can customise this how you see fit.
        writer.WriteRawValue(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => true;

    public override bool CanRead => false;
}
```

Then:

```
var stuff = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new MyClass 
{ MyA = new A { Banana = "cheese" }, 
  MyB = new A { Banana = "notype"} },
new JsonSerializerSettings{ TypeNameHandling=TypeNameHandling.Auto });
                                                        
Console.WriteLine(stuff); // {"MyA":{"$type":"whatever, here","Banana":"cheese"},"MyB":{"Banana":"notype"}}
```

Note, however, that you can not deserialize BACK to your type this way because the type info is missing for `MyB`

```
var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(stuff, 
    new JsonSerializerSettings{ TypeNameHandling=TypeNameHandling.Auto });
```

that will throw

> Unhandled exception. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Could not create an instance of type ISomeInterfaceA. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path 'MyB.Banana', line 1, position 69.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of that possibility but was hoping I wouldn't have to resort to this as there is a downside : your solution is recursive and would affect all children and sub-children, whereas I was hoping to target the presence or absence of "$type" at a specific level without affecting sub-objects too

Comment: In the end I used a variation on this. Instead of a converter to skip typing information, I created a converter that _emits_ type information, then iterates over all properties of a class by reflection and serializes its membes one by one. This way I have full control. Not quite as easy as I'd hoped, but gets the job done